# Cannot acess a class from virtual directory

Tags: asp.net

Using C# in an ASP.NET application, I have a class `Class1` in the `App_Code` folder. I can create a `c1` object and use it in Default.aspx.cs page, and it works fine. However, when I create a Virtual Directory and run it from there, it gives me the following error:

> CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Class1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive

Comment: The virtual directory you're creating: are you doing this on your development machine or are you migrating your app to some other machine?

Comment: in development machine

Comment: Is the code physically in the same directory it was, or in a new directory (the one the virtual directory points to?)